# SQL script to SSIS expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I have the below T-SQL line of query that I'm trying to translate into Visual studio SSIS expression into derived column task.

So `tableA` has just `[Work item /Submission no#]` column, but I need to split them into two column like `SubmissionCommon` and `SubmissionNumber` in TableB when below case is executed.

```
CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING([Work item /Submission no#], 4, 2)) = 1
       THEN LEFT([Work item /Submission no#], 15)
       ELSE LEFT([Work item /Submission no#], 16)
END AS SubmissionCommon,
[Work item /Submission no#] AS SubmissionNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I will suggested that you first add a derived column *(you can name it `IsNumeric`)*, with the following expression:

```
(DT_NUMERIC, 18, 2)SUBSTRING([Work item /Submission no#], 4, 2) == (DT_NUMERIC, 18, 2)SUBSTRING([Work item /Submission no#], 4, 2) ? 1 : 0
```

Then near the bottom of the Derived Column Transform Editor window, click Configure Error Output. You need to tell SSIS to **Ignore failure on Error**

Add another Derived Column connect to the first on with the following expression

```
REPLACENULL([IsNumeric],0) == 1 ? LEFT([Work item /Submission no#], 15) : LEFT([Work item /Submission no#], 16)
```

Because the first one may throws an error

For detailed informations just follow this article:

- http://bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/ssis/915/check-isnumeric-with-derived-column-transform-in-ssis-package

## Update 1 - Screenshots

*Based on your comments, i will provide some screenshots*

**Data Flow overview**

[image]

**First Derived Column**

[image]

**First Derived Column Error Output Configuration**

[image]

**Second Derived Column**

[image]

Comment: I just saw this and sorry for not asking on this earlier. So I need to add two columns in the derived column 1) IsNumeric with above formula, 2)SubmissionCommon with above exp (replacing IsNumeric - expression), but it gives me an error for the second one

Comment: No, add 2 derived column transformations, every column in one component: (2 derived columns transformation -> on column in each transformation): first `Isnumeric` then `SubmissionControl`

Comment: If you are confused i can add some screenshots, give me a reply if you are interested

Comment: ya .. I would be more grateful. Thanks so much.

Comment: I tried the same and It worked like a charm. Thanks a ton! and thanks much for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should work for you:

```
(DT_NUMERIC, 18, 2)SUBSTRING([Work item /Submission no#], 4, 2) == 
(DT_NUMERIC, 18, 2)SUBSTRING([Work item /Submission no#], 4, 2) ? 
LEFT([Work item /Submission no#], 15): 
LEFT([Work item /Submission no#], 16)
```

Tried to format for this site but you might have to delete some of the returns. This should cast your column to numeric and compare it to itself (thus if the conversion fails it will be NULL and not equal).

Edit: Here is the string un-formatted:

```
(DT_NUMERIC, 18, 2)SUBSTRING([Work item /Submission no#], 4, 2) == (DT_NUMERIC, 18, 2)SUBSTRING([Work item /Submission no#], 4, 2) ? LEFT([Work item /Submission no#], 15): LEFT([Work item /Submission no#], 16)
```

You may also need to match the precision and scale specifications for DT_NUMERIC to match your own requirements.

Comment: Apologize if I am asking basic question. I'n new to SSIS and getting to know  stuff. Should I use the above expression to both the Derived columns ? like ColA = "above expression" and next row ColB=" above Expression"

Comment: Doesn't look like there formula in the second column in your initial post. You should be able to simply use [Work item /Submission no#] as SubmissionNumber.

Answer (score 1):

if you prefer c# script component (make sure to add input and output columns):

```
string test = Rows.YourRowToTest;
int someNum; //catches output

Row.ColumnName = int.TryParse(test.Substring(4,2),out someNum) == false
                 ?test.Substring(1, 16)
                 :test.Substring(1, 15);
```

Comment: even if i posted a different method. I prefer to do this using a script component because it is more powerful +1